# CSS block float left margin to full parent width

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div class="main_block">
    <div class="block">
       <p>some title</p>
       <img src="some_image.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="block">
       <p>some title</p>
       <img src="some_image.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="block">
       <p>some title</p>
       <img src="some_image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.main_block
{
    width: 600px;
}

div.main_block div.block
{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
div.main_block div.block:first-child
{
    margin-left: 0;
}

div.main_block div.block:hover
{
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
div.main_block div.active
{
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

is there something to make it automatically?, thus everytime the main width changes, I have to change the children margins and width, or how to make it more efficiently?, also if I add the border to the blocks while hovering them, if it was on a max margin and width, the border will add more width, and here begins the problems

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `margin-left: 100px` to be `auto`:

```
div.main_block div.block
{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aHZXx/

Comment: hmmm... the margin-left: auto, don't margin the blocks, if they are floated left, i mean can they calculate automatically the width, and then make the margin at full width of the parent?

Comment: @Hello Then they'd be displayed inline if they were floated left? Do you want them all on the same line but separated with a gap that's the width of the parent? Or something else?

Comment: yes, separated with the gap, and that gap will be the margin-left, i think that here i will need to use percent, but if i change the parent width, i will need to edit the percent again, thats not efficient

Answer (score 1):

you can use % instead of px.
for exemple :

```
div.main_block div.block
{

width: 10%;



   margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the **border-changing-width** problem (telling the browser to include the border and padding in the `width` calculation):

```
div.main_block div.block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Many experts are recommending using it on all elements:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```